# aws sts get-session-token ... --token-code ... fails with InvalidClientTokenId, but MFA console login working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to retrieve session token on the AWS CLI like so:

`aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn-string --token-code mfacode`

where

- `arn-string` is copied from the IAM management console, security credentials for the assigned
  MFA device,format like `arn:aws:iam:<number>:mfa/<name>`
- `mfacode` is taken from the registered virtual mfa device

### error:

`An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

However, I use that MFA device to login to the console in the browser just fine

I have only a default profile in my ~/.aws/, but I don't see how this would have any influence.

### tried this:

1. try multiple time to ensure no mfa flip-over has happened
2. delete MFA device assignment and reassign device -- same error
3. ommitting `--token-code` in hope to have it prompt me for the MFA device token -- same error
4. using the `arn:aws:iam:<number>:user/<name>` -- same error as can be expected since  the `aws get-session-id help`  clearly states it needs to be the arn of the mfa device

I figure this has to do with arn-string rather than the token, but what ?
Any idea on what causes this problem most welcome.

Regards,
Olaf

Comment: also tried --profile default parameter so it can use my configured region, but same error

Comment: other operations with CLI work, like `aws s3 ls`? Or the issue is only related to `sts`?

Comment: @Marcin: yes, I use access key from my default credentials. But I don't want to leave them active permanantly. Could this be some sort of policy blocking use of my MFA device ?

Comment: have you also included the `mfa_serial` arn in your `~/.aws/config` file under your profile? Reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html#cli-configure-role-mfa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. **maafk**'s comment nails it down. For the records and to the next poor soul stumbling into this problem:

The profile used must have the`mfa_serial` entry. In my case added the *arn-string* for the mfa-device to my local default profile in `~/.aws/config` like so:

`[default]`

`region = eu-central-1`

`mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam:<number>:mfa/<name>`

This string can be found in the console, IAM service under the user, security credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add an edge case for anyone who might have bungled like me. Olaf clearly pointed out above that the mfa arn code is taken from the registered virtual mfa device in the AWS console. I had assumed that it just includes your user name, but it's actually the name you specify when you assign the MFA device. So mine happened to be my email address / user name, but other's were naming their devices differently and I couldn't understand why generating a temporary token was failing for them. In short - make sure you correctly get the arn string from the console first!

[image]